# as400: C headers include

Tags: c, file, header, include, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to include another member in a source member.

```
#include "/QSYS.LIB/MYLIB.LIB/TEST.FILE/HEADER.MBR"
```

When I compile with `crtcmod module(main) srcfile(test) srcmbr(main)`,
I get an error which says the include file is not found.

If use the command `dsplnk obj('QSYS.LIB/MYLIB.LIB/TEST.FILE/HEADER.MBR')`,

it does find the file. Why doesn't my C include work?

I must use this file system because it's the only one I have access to.

Comment: Can you just `#include "HEADER.MBR"` and instruct the compiler to add `/QSYS.LIB/MYLIB.LIB/TEST.FILE` to its include-file search path?  The traditional option for that would be `-I/QSYS.LIB/MYLIB.LIB/TEST.FILE`, but I have no idea whether that's applicable to your particular compiler.

Comment: Yes I can, though I get the same error with my include changed to "HEADER.MBR" and the additional compile option incdir('QSYS.LIB/MYLIB.LIB/TEST.FILE').

Comment: Perhaps it's an access control issue.  Given that the file exists, can the compile process actually open and read it?

Comment: Yes, I compiled the header into a module without problem. It's only when I want to compile the other file which uses functions from the header. I expected the ILE module to find the needed functions when binding the modules together, but it complains about undefined functions so I guess I need to include it as well.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your toolchain, so I'm perhaps not the best person to help you.  I note, however, that you now seem to have said two rather different things: (1) that the compiler cannot find the `HEADER.MBR` file, and (2) that the linker cannot find certain functions you expect it to find.

Comment: does the link statement include the parameter: `-pthread`?  because that library (or the `rt` library)  is the one that contains the semaphore functions

Comment: `incdir('QSYS.LIB/MYLIB.LIB/TEST.FILE')` would only be found if the /root directory somehow happened to be the compile job's current directory (which seems unlikely). The path has no leading slash, so it's a relative rather than absolute path.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. All I had to do was to use QSYS paths.

```
#include "HEADER" // if in the same file
```

or

```
#include "MYLIB/MYFILE(HEADER)"
```

For the absolute path include to work, I had to compile from a stream file which compiles from absolute paths. But then, the directive #pragma mapinc that includes my display file wouldn't work anymore because it takes a QSYS path.

Answer (score 3):

The IBM i C and C++ compilers have special code to handle includes. When it finds an include such as

`#include <stdio.h>`

It will search for this include in one of two ways:

- If your source is in a source physical file (using the `SRCFILE` parameter), it will search through its search path for a file called `H` with a member named `STDIO` and include it. The default search path is the `QSYSINC` library and all the libraries on your library list.
- If your source is in the IFS (using the `SRCSTMF` parameter), it will search through its IFS search path which defaults to `/QIBM/include`.

To find your own headers, you can do one of two things:

- If your source is in a source physical file, you can create a file called `H` and add your headers as members of that file. Then add the library containing that file to your library list.
- If your source is in the IFS, you can put your header in to an IFS directory and add that directory to the `INCDIR` parameter to `CRTBNDC` or `CRTCMOD`.

eg.

```
CPYF FROMFILE(MYLIB/TEST) TOFILE(MULIB/H) FROMMBR(HEADER) TOMBR(HEADER) CRTFILE(*YES)

ADDLIBLE MYLIB

crtcmod module(main) srcfile(test) srcmbr(main)
```